# Separating data frame by comma in R

Tags: r, string, csv, matrix

I'm new to R so I apologize if my terminology is incorrect here. I have a .csv file that has two rows with irrelevant information (the date, and another global header) and then has the relevant data starting at row 3 with all the column headers. I have figured out that the code

```
my.files <- list.files()
file <- readLines(my.files[1])
temp2 <- data.frame((file[-c(1,2)]))
```

removes the first two rows of data and stores the remaining rows in a data frame, however, the data frame that is saved only has one column with each of the intended columns separated by a comma: `"Frame ID,Delta Time, Head Pos X, Head Pos Y, Head Pos Z..."` The rows beneath have the correct responses, but are similarly squished into a single column separated by commas.

How do I either 1) rewrite the above code to end with a matrix that is missing the first two rows, or 2) separate a single column that is comma delimited into multiple columns within a data frame?

I have seen the `strsplit()` function but have not been able to apply it appropriately.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe just use `read.csv(...., skip=2)` to skip the first two rows? It will probably parse the rest of the file just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data <- read.table("path to file", skip = 2, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
```

It will read the file, after skipping 2 lines and the 3rd will be the header